# Can we use Custom Labels in Einstein Bot?

Tags: einstein-chatbot, einstein-bots

I am learning to build bot, and have a question to all. Can we use Custom Label in Einstein Bot?

In [this](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.bots_service_context_system_variables.htm&type=5) document it mentions the use of context variables, but it doesn't say about Custom Label.